# Twig "_self" variable

Tags: symfony, twig

Where is documented the existence of this keyword? (I guess it is a constant, rather than an object, right?).

Anyway, I'd like to know where it is documented, to see if there are other keywords that I don't know about.

Thanks

Comment: Be careful that `_self` [is deprecated](http://symfony.com/blog/security-release-twig-1-20-0) everywhere but used with the `{% import %}` tag.

Answer (score 11):

This doesn't really answer the question, but I think it's important to mention it.
The `_self` itself is *not really* deprecated nor removed, but its usage is!

If you look for deprecated features in Twig 2.*, you'll find [there are none](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/2.x/deprecated.html).
So, you may think falsely that you're safe, or scratch your head (like I did) in finding why did it stop working in v2.0.

But actually, in Twig v1, `_self` was an object, with which you could do `_self.templateName`, or call Twig macros with it. Its usage as object was [deprecated](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/1.x/deprecated.html#globals) but it worked.

In Twig v2, `_self` is no more an object but a string, which actually holds the templates name (the previous value of `_self.templateName`).

So, if you used it in Twig v1 as an object - your code will fail in Twig v2.
Anyway, it seems like a bit messy resolution of the `_self` issue.

Answer (score 6):

I found it here:

http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/templates.html

Under Global Variables